# Using jQuery to change style of clicked element and removing that style from other elements with same class

Tags: javascript, jquery

**EDIT: fixed it! Thanks to those who said to post my HTML - I looked at it, and didn't realize that I had the "appname" class twice.**

```
<li class="<?php echo $apid; ?> appname appname_getinfo appname_<?php echo $apid; ?>">
       <span class="appname"><?php echo $apname; ?></span>
</li>
```

**So, I removed the "" and it works!**

Say that I have three elements with a class:

EL ONE

EL TWO

EL THREE

When I click on EL ONE, I would like to make it bold. When I click on EL TWO, it should become bold and EL ONE should become normal weight. When I click on EL THREE next, it should become bold and EL TWO becomes normal weight.

MY SCRIPT:

```
//// app info ////
$("li.appname_getinfo").click(function(){

    var appID = this.className.split(' ')[0];
    $.get("wishlist/appinfo.php?pw=R32kd63DL&apid=" + appID, function(data){                                
        $("div#appinfo").html(data);                            
    });

    $("div#appinfo").show();

    $(".appname").css("font-weight", "normal");
    $(this).css("font-weight", "bold");


});
```

I thought that I could set all with class "appname" to normal, then change $(this) to bold, but it doesn't work. (it disallows any to be bold).

Comment: Can you please post the HTML of the three elements?

Comment: Your `click` function does not seem to target an element with the class `appname`, but `appname_getinfo`, unless it also has the class `appname` you're probably not hitting the right target. If you post some actual `HTML` this would probably be easier?

Comment: @adeneo it does have both classes.

Answer (score 0):

first thing, as a rule of thumb, add classes not css directly from js. Secondly you are applying the bold rule to `".appname"` and not to `"li.appname_getinfo"`

Comment: Actually, the elements have the classes "appname" and "appname_getinfo". I added the "appname_getinfo" class because my header had the class "appname" as well, and I didn't want to call this click function on the header.

Comment: then, won't applying bold rule to "appname" also apply to the header? and can you provide a fiddle for this? it'll help

Comment: @ParthThakkar no, I'm not applying a bold rule to appname. I'm applying it to $(this)

Answer (score 0):

Need to use an `$().each` to add handler to each item. My code is:

```
$('.appName').each(
  function(index, item){
    $(item).click(
      function(e) {
        $('.appName').css('fontWeight', 'normal');
        $(this).css('fontWeight', 'bold');
    });
});
```

Tested in Chrome and it seems to work as you describe

Answer (score 0):

While I suspect the problem is, as mentioned above, the mismatch in class-names, one other reason could be because you have a container inside of the "li" element and that container is set to font-weight normal. You are setting the bold on the LI element, but if the element inside of it is normal font, then setting it on the LI won't do anything... 
e.g.

```
...
<style>
span { font-weight:normal; }
</style>
...
<ul>
   <li class="appName"><span>this text will not bold when you bold the LI because it's in a span, and spans are styled with normal font-weight</span>
   </li>
<ul>
```

Chrome's dev tools will help...